# Trouble with quill font sizes

Tags: quill

I am using quill js and making a fully responsive editor that will scale font-size with the container, using the view width property.

I have it fully built except for one problem:

Even though I am using `prepareFormat()`, (for times where the cursor is at one point and no other text is selected) the font size will change on occasion to the highest default font inside of the quill minified file, which in version 0.20.1, happens to be 48px. I have tried putting my own numbers into the quilljs `FONT_SIZES` object, but only sometimes it would select them properly.

The thing I am most confused about is that if I highlight them, the letters will change to exactly what I would like them to be, whereas for the `prepareFormat()` fails to change it into any number but a preset in `FONT_SIZES`.

What event should I tie `prepareFormat()` to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quill 0.20.1 uses [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) which only allows 1-7 as valid font sizes. Quill 1.0 has no such limitation.

Comment: I just commented out the values in FONT_SIZES and used prepareFormat / formatText functions to grab my sizes.